# how to construct training vectors of word n-gram using TF-IDF

Tags: python, nlp, svm, tf-idf

My task is to do the text classification with svm, using word n-gram as features. 
Before using TF-IDF, my code is:

```
word_dic = ngram.wordNgrams(text, n)
freq_term_vector = [word_dic[gram] if gram in word_dic else 0 for gram in global_vector]
X.append(freq_term_vector)
```

And It works well. However, when I tried TF-IDF, the code is below:

```
freq_term_vector = [word_dic[gram] if gram in word_dic else 0 for gram in global_vector]
tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf.fit(freq_term_vector)
X.append(tfidf.transform(freq_term_vector).toarray())
```

The training part can be done, but when the program ran to the predict part, it said

```
 clf.predict(X_test)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 223, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 207, in decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 83, in safe_sparse_dot
    return np.dot(a, b)
ValueError: shapes (1100,1,38) and (1,11) not aligned: 38 (dim 2) != 1 (dim 0)
```

The training method and predict method are the same. How can I solve this align problem? Could anyone help me check my code above or give me some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the append, try the following:

```
...
X = tfidf.transform(freq_term_vector)
...
X_test = tfidf.transform(freq_term_vector_test)
clf.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I see, the problem is actually with the append method. I tried the extend method and it works well.Thank you!